# PHP tiles from csv

Tags: php, csv

I've got csv file with following data

```
1stFOTOname, 2ndFOTOname, 3rdFOTOname, 4thFOTOname
1stFOTOurl, 2ndFOTOurl, 3rdFOTOurl, 4thFOTOurl
1stFOTOsize, 2ndFOTOsize, 3rdFOTOsize, 4thFOTOsize
```

I would like to display fotos as tiles on webpage with PHP. Every foto (url) should be displayed as square tile with name and size under the foto. Tiles should be displayed in grid style.

Could you give me any example to do this? I don't even know what to start with.

Comment: cool ... show your efforts

Comment: It does not work like that. First you try to solve the problem yourself, and if unsuccessful then ask the question. Start with a sample HTML.

Comment: "hello google" didn't  solve the problem. Why you're so conservative?

Comment: Create your html page at least!

Comment: HTML is static so I need PHP to display even one tile from CSV. Em I right?

Comment: Maybe start with https://eval.in/815020.